# How is reddit's link karma calculated?

Tags: reddit

I couldn't find it easily in [their FAQ](http://www.reddit.com/help/faq#WhatisthatnumbernexttousernamesAndwhatiskarma): When does your link karma increase 1 point?
I don't think it's a one-one relationship with votes, as some of my stuff got upvoted and it didn't change immediately

What about comment karma? Is it the same formula but for votes on comments?

Comment: Is that formula tag a bug @rchern?

Comment: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/717/questions-shouldnt-have-two-tags-that-are-identical

Comment: Maybe it's a caching issue, meaning that your karma is not updated live, but calculated every once in a while.

Comment: That may be a good enough reason @GoodEnough

Comment: Doesn't seem to be caching / recalculating -- I have the same situation, and there haven't been any up/down votes for nearly a month.  Screenshot, fwiw: http://imgur.com/Zkvrh7K

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit):

> Users gain one point of link karma
>   when another user votes up their
>   submission and lose a point when a
>   user votes down their submission.
>   Individual comments may also be voted
>   up or down by other users and result
>   in a user's comment karma. Users stop
>   losing karma after their submission
>   reaches 0. This is not the case for
>   comments.
>
> Karma points are also not gained from votes for direct submissions of Reddit-hosted 
>   posts to reddits (also known as "self" posts, usually indicated by "self.(name of sub-
>   reddit)" listed next to the name of the post); this was implemented by the 
>   administrators to counteract against "karma-whoring"

Comment: Hmm, WP did say this (but doesn't, as of 2013.Feb).

As the questioner notes, that formula doesn't jibe with reality.  For example, screenshot: http://imgur.com/Zkvrh7K

Answer (score 0):

You get points for the first 12 hours. When you accumulate a lot of points you get taxed 1/3rd of the points so basically you receive approximately 2/3rds of the points link gets from up-votes within the first 12 hours.